# 403 : The provided user credentials did not have necessary access-scopes querying email messages using Beta API

Tags: email, debugging, permissions, jwt, microsoft-graph-api

I have to two API keys, that appear to be defined with exactly the same API permissions:

```
Calendars.Read          offline_access 
Calendars.Read.Shared   openid         
email                   profile        
Files.Read.All          Sites.Read.All 
Mail.Read               User.Read      
Mail.Read.Shared
```

I realize that some some of these are redundant (e.g. Calendars.Read and Calendars.Read.Shared) and may be over permissive for what I'm doing. My intent is to narrow them down once I understand this problem a bit better.

My applications is trying to query both outlook Calendar and Outlook mail. When I use one of they keys, it works, w/ no problems. If use the other key, I get a 403 back from the API and the message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "message": "\r\n The provided user credentials did not have necessary access-scopes ",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-07-19T19:25:33",
      "request-id": "e1c703df-4fed-4219-b2d4-1436ea762987"
    }
  }
}
```

When I look the access tokens jwt that come back for each key, they have very different scp fields:

**working scp** : Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared email Files.Read.All Mail.Read Mail.Read.Shared openid profile Sites.Read.All User.Read"

**failing scp** : Calendars.Read.Shared Files.Read.All Mail.Read.Shared Sites.Read.All User.Read profile openid email

The application scope is as follows:
`offline_access User.Read Files.Read.All Mail.Read.Shared Calendars.Read.Shared Sites.Read.All`

The URL and request look like this for the outlook mail search:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query`

```
    "requests": [
        {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "meeting"
                }
            },
            "from": 0,
            "enableTopResults": "true",
            "entityTypes": [
                "microsoft.graph.message"
            ],
            "size": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas on what's happening here or how to debug further?

Thanks.